# I don't understand how to characterize a class similar to a DTO but with validation

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, spring-mvc

I have the entity class.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I use the following class to fill it.

```
public class UserData {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastname;

    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@acme\\.com)$")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 12, message = "Password length must be 12 chars minimum!")
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Which is passed as the request body in the controller.

```
@PostMapping("/api/auth/signup")
    ResponseEntity<?> singUp(@Valid @RequestBody UserData user, Errors errors) { }
```

As far as I know there is no need to add any logic in `DTO`. So, what type of object can the `UserData` class be classified as?
I'm still not very good at design patterns and I'm worried about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classifying the UserData class is subjective. There is no standard design pattern that this follows, however this is something you will see in many different frameworks.

For a moment, let us rename the class to **Create**User**Request**. This gives us a little more context on how we should is it. It is a request to create a new user sent in an HTTP request. The `@xxx` annotations are used be the web framework to execute basic data validations. The important point here is the the DTO itself does not use these validations — *something else does*.

Within the context of web applications that return HTML pages, this is a DTO often referred to as a View Model. If the application is a web API which returns JSON or XML, people just tend to call it a DTO without needing to further classify it.

Since code external to the UserData class uses the `@xxx` annotations, the UserData class does not contain logic. It more accurately contains *meta data* read using class reflection for the purpose of driving data validations.

I wouldn't worry about trying to classify this class or assigning a design pattern to this. Calling it a data transfer object is good enough.